# Is it possible to pass value to SCSS variable from Typescript in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, sass, gulp, gruntjs

I am looking for the possible solution where I can pass value to `SCSS` variable. I am pretty much aware since `SCSS` is a pre-processor and it's nearly impossible. But there has to be some solution where we can easily access the variable and change or retrieve it's value.

Can't we put `watch` using `grunt` or `gulp` to constantly check for possible changes in `SCSS` file and based on that we get appropriate css? (I am aware that to retrieve those changes we need to refresh the page.) Is it really possible?

**EDIT**

Let say I have one SCSS file: `style.scss`

```
$background : #c9def5;


.nav-tabs {
    background-color: $background;
}
```

Initially when css is generated it looks like this

```
.nav-tabs {
        background-color: #c9def5;
    }
```

Now In my application there is facility of changing theme of the application dynamically. So for that I need to pass color value to `$background` in `SCSS` file and need to change it. 
Now say I have changed Theme color to something like `#d9d9d9`

So all I want is to pass value `#d9d9d9` to `$background` and that modifies the css

```
  .nav-tabs {
        background-color: #c9def5;
    }
```

Is it really possible? If yes then how can I achieve it?

PS: I have seen many such questions available on SO but didn't got any satisfactory answer there.

Comment: What is the question? Do you think you could show an example of what you want to achieve because this isn't making any sense.

Comment: @NeilLunn I am sorry If you misunderstood the concept. I have updated the question with the scenario.

Comment: The example demonstrates your intent better that the text you added, which is why I asked. If your intention is to do "theming" then there are ways around this. Some (most common) approaches are based on switching classes instead. None of these involve writing to an SCSS file during runtime. So I wanted to get to your objective because your question was about how you "thought" it is done. You should simply directly ask a question (or search) about switching themes in your application instead.

Comment: Actually in theme there might be chances that controls(let say button or Link) have different color scheme code. So this is why I thought to Convert my CSS to SCSS .

Comment: Refer https://github.com/medialize/sass.js/